# Knockout + validation of some html elements collaboratively

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, validation

I have a situation here, i have a div with some html elements which are already binded with the knockout.js framework.

The thing i was trying was to create a single error panel which on save button of particular div validates the html elements and generates the error messages.

Any ideas how to do it from knockout or we need knockout + jquery??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with following way:
For example add simple text property to your view mode like

```
function ViewModel()
{
  this.error = ko.observable('');
}
```

Apply this property to your error panel maybe like this:

```
<div class='error' data-bind="visible:error != '', text:error"></div>
```

And when you want show some error just set message to error property. Of course this example is very simple but you can use it like start point.